# Swift universal framework depending on pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ios-universal-framework

I'm developing a small Swift framework that depends on Alamofire. I'm using it as an embedded framework of an app belonging to the same workspace and it works perfectly.

The problem arises when I want to build an universal framework with an aggregate target. Then, when executing the script to generate the  framework it fails with the message `No such module 'Alamofire'`, referring to an `import Alamofire` in one of my source files.

This is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'FSIBackend' do
  pod 'SwiftLint'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
```

This is the script to generate the framework. It works with other frameworks without Pods dependencies so I assume that is ok:

```
set -e

# Setup
FRAMEWORK_NAME="${1}"
BUILD_DIR="${SRCROOT}/build"
OUTPUT_DIR="${HOME}/Desktop/"
OUTPUT="${OUTPUT_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

rm -rf "${BUILD_DIR}"
rm -rf "${OUTPUT}"
mkdir -p "${OUTPUT_DIR}"

# Build
xcodebuild -target "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -configuration Release -arch arm64 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s only_active_arch=no defines_module=yes -sdk "iphoneos"
xcodebuild -target "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -configuration Release -arch x86_64 -arch i386 only_active_arch=no defines_module=yes -sdk "iphonesimulator"

# Copy the device version of framework to output.
cp -r "${BUILD_DIR}/Release-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" "${OUTPUT}"

# Replace the framework executable within the framework with a new version created by merging the device and simulator frameworks' executables with lipo.
lipo -create -output "${OUTPUT}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/Release-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/Release-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}"

# Copy the Swift module mappings for the simulator into the framework. The device mappings already exist from step 6.
cp -r "${BUILD_DIR}/Release-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" "${OUTPUT}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule"

# Delete build.
rm -rf "${BUILD_DIR}"
```

The question is that I don't know how to build my framework depending on Alamofire. Do I have to create a podspec for my framework and use it via CocoaPods? This is the first time I create a universal framework depending on a pod so I don't know if I'm doing something impossible.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you post the script you run in Aggregate target?

Comment: @mag_zbc done :)

Comment: Recently I also had issues with bulding a framework out of workspace that used pods. You can try changing `xcodebuild -target "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}"` to `xcodebuild -workspace "YourWorkspace.xcworkspace" -scheme YourScheme`

Comment: Thanks @mag_zbc but I tried and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I could accomplish it taking into account the advice given from @mag_zbc, thank you.

I had to modify the framework generation this way:

```
set -e

# Setup
WORKSPACE="${1}"
FRAMEWORK_NAME="${2}"
BUILD_DIR="${SRCROOT}/build"
OUTPUT_DIR="${HOME}/Desktop/"
OUTPUT="${OUTPUT_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
CONFIGURATION="${CONFIGURATION}"

rm -rf "${BUILD_DIR}"
rm -rf "${OUTPUT}"
mkdir -p "${OUTPUT_DIR}"

# Build the framework for device and for simulator (using all needed architectures).
xcodebuild -workspace "${WORKSPACE}" -scheme "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -arch x86_64 -arch i386 only_active_arch=no defines_module=yes -sdk "iphonesimulator" clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator
xcodebuild -workspace "${WORKSPACE}" -scheme "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -arch arm64 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s only_active_arch=no defines_module=yes -sdk "iphoneos" clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos

# Copy the device version of framework to output.
cp -r "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" "${OUTPUT}"

# Replace the framework executable within the framework with a new version created by merging the device and simulator frameworks' executables with lipo.
lipo -create -output "${OUTPUT}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}"

# Copy the Swift module mappings for the simulator into the framework. The device mappings already exist from step 6.
cp -r "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" "${OUTPUT}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule"

# Delete build.
rm -rf "${BUILD_DIR}"
```

After generated, and added to the consumer app, the only thing left to do is to use Cocoapods in the consumer app to get Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

Comment: You Sir saved my life! I was starting to get really depressed with all that library shit but then there was light at the end of the tunnel.. it was your question / answer that brought joy to my heart. After I successfully built the library I was feeling like I was on the path to heaven. Only the integration of it could make me a sinner and go to hell. However, it worked out perfectly fine!

Comment: @emenegro This script does not work with latest xcode 12 also if i try to use it with -UseModernBuildSystem=NO then xcode complains as its deprecated. Any more workarounds to get this working ?